# Anomy vs Lawlessness

Tags: synonyms

Considering the etymology of [**anomie**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anomie), could *lawlessness* be considered the Anglo-Saxon translation of this learned word of Greek origin?

Comment: Short answer: Greeks forms of words are often used in literary criticism, philosophy and other disciplines for purposes of theoretical precision. They are, as it were, a starting point for the ideas associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

#### No.

**As you have pointed out, *anomie* comes from the greek *anomos* which means lawless, but you are wrong in assuming that lawlessness is the Anglo-Saxon translation from the Greek word.**

Lawlessness can be broken down into:

'law',

> the system of rules which a particular country or community recognizes as regulating the actions of its members and which it may enforce by the imposition of penalties.

'-less'  [suffix]

> not having; free from.

and '-ness' [suffix]

> denoting a state or condition.

So lawlessness means 'the state of being free from law'.

The word 'law' itself derives from Old English *lagu* from Old Norse *lag*, which means 'something laid down or fixed'.

**As you can see, lawlessness derives from the Old Norse for 'law', not from a Greek translation.**

---

On the subject of translations, the word 'translate' means:

> To express the sense of (words or text) in another language

In other words, it is the depiction of similar ideas/things using words from another language, which *are not necessarily related*.

**Which is different from etymology and derivation.**

To illustrate my point, the word 'fish' comes from the Germanic *fiscian*, whereas the French word for fish, *poisson*, comes from Latin *piscis* - they are not a translation of each other, nor is the etymology the same, despite meaning the same thing.

The same goes for **anomie** and **lawlessness**, which, despite *meaning* similar things, are not a translation of each other.

Source: [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: I have assumed nothing: hence my question here.

Comment: @User26328 sorry, not trying to condecend :)